Scim API vs normal user add/delete api for zoom
I am trying to understand the difference between using SCIM API for Zoom
https://developers.zoom.us/docs/api/rest/reference/scim-api/methods/#overview

vs Zoom user API
https://developers.zoom.us/docs/api/rest/reference/user/methods/#operation/users

what would be the difference here between both of them?
It looks like both of them have

Get all users
Create new users
Deactivate a user

Api. if we are building custom user access management, what difference would it be?

SCIM is a standardized way to approach these tasks - in theory, you can write SCIM client code once and use it interoperably with multiple SCIM servers. The non-SCIM API you mentioned is a proprietary Zoom user management API and any code written to call that API will not be reusable with other apps/services.
